# How to have event only when parent is clicked but not when children (two levels down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, menu

I'm doing a side menu, that hides and reveals a submenu when the parent **li** element is clicked, and I'm almost done. The problem is that if the **li** child (two levels down) is clicked it hides the submenu as well.

The parent should be the only one able to trigger the event.

Here you have a simplified version of the Html, CSS and JavaScript (jQuery):

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $( "li.has-submenu" ).on( 'click', function (e) {
    if( $("#submenu").hasClass( "hides" ) ){
      $("#submenu").slideDown().toggleClass( "hides" );
    } else {
      $("#submenu").slideUp().toggleClass( "hides" );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#submenu {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="has-submenu">
      <a href="#">Overview </a>
      <ul id="submenu" class="nav hide">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Overview </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Account Settings </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Tasks </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            Help </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Account Settings </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Tasks </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Help </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Do you know how to fix this behavior?

Comment: it works better with class 'hide' ;)

Comment: Put your closing `</li>` of your has-submenu where it should be, after its `<a>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `.stopPropagation()` function on the elements you don't want triggering your parent :

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $( "li.has-submenu" ).on( 'click', function (e) {
    if( $("#submenu").hasClass( "hides" ) ){
      $("#submenu").slideDown().toggleClass( "hides" );
    } else {
      $("#submenu").slideUp().toggleClass( "hides" );
    }
  });
  
  $( "li.has-submenu li" ).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#submenu {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="has-submenu">
      <a href="#">Overview </a>
      <ul id="submenu" class="nav hide">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Overview </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Account Settings </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Tasks </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            Help </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Account Settings </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Tasks </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Help </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the nav>li>a display block and put the id on that. That way the link takes up the whole width of the li and when you click it, it won't affect the submenu because the submenu isn't in the a element

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is move your closing `</li>` tag where it should be, after it's `<a>` element:

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $( ".has-submenu" ).on( 'click', function (e) {
    if( $("#submenu").hasClass( "hides" ) ){
      $("#submenu").slideDown().toggleClass( "hides" );
    } else {
      $("#submenu").slideUp().toggleClass( "hides" );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#submenu {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="has-submenu">
      <a href="#">Overview </a>
    </li>
      <ul id="submenu" class="nav hide">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Overview </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Account Settings </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Tasks </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            Help </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Account Settings </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Tasks </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Help </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```